# Username check comes back as username already exist when it doesnt

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a code that checks if a username exists or not, but when I run the code and enter in a username i inserted into my database using phpmyadmin it says the username dosent exist, am wondering where i went wrong?

here is my php code:

```
<?php
require_once 'connect.php';

$conn = dbConnect();
if (isset($_POST['username'])) 
{
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id)
                               FROM users
                               WHERE username = :username");

$sql->execute(array(":username" => $_POST['username']));
$rows_number =  $sql->fetchColumn();

 if($rows_number ==0)
 {
   echo "Username doesn't exist";
   exit;
 }
else
{
  echo "Username already exists";
  exit;
}
}

?>
```

here is my php connect.php:

```
<?php

function dbConnect(){
$db = null;
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username ="user";
$db_pass ="pass";
$db_name = "accounts";

try{
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname'.$db_name,$db_username,$db_pass);

}
catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo '<p>Cannot connect to database !!</p>';
  exit;
}
return $db;
}

?>
```

Comment: Have you checked the value of `$rows_number`?

Comment: no i will do that now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as I do not have 50+ rep I can't comment but post your connect.php code and exclude the username and password so I can see if its the connect.php that's giving the problem

Edit: your problem lye's here:

```
   ';dbname'.$db_name,$db_username,$db_pass);
```

it should be

```
 ';dbname='
```

and then append on your variable $db_name. Further explanation is the ';dbname is equal to the value you gave your variable.

Comment: no problem am just learning PDO but [this guy on youtube explains it well]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ncrjieoiTrg&list=PL0BBakFmJ-JlELdmy9LX7c_l7V4XMad84, [also check out the php PDO manual]http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php it's hard to understand but watch the video and use the manual and you will be alright.

Answer (score -2):

You may not have initialized the query statement

/* create a prepared statement */

```
<?php
    $stmt =  $mysqli->stmt_init();
    if ($stmt->prepare("SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $city);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($district);

    /* fetch value */
    $stmt->fetch();

    printf("%s is in district %s\n", $city, $district);

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}

   /* close connection */
    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: It always makes me wonder what makes people to write such answers.

Comment: its cause google is their friend, now thats using your common sense :)